# Archiva files disappearing

Tags: java, archiva

I have an issue with Archiva 2.2.1, files disappear. When I brose in the archiva web interface, the artifact link is there, but when I click on it I get a 404. 
This happens for the release and snapshot repositories.

Anyone else have experience with this?